# GET List Likes Using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search the user's list of likes, to know if he liked my page or not

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/likes

I also want to know I did not follow my profile or not

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/???
```

Comment: what for exactly do you want to know if the user liked your page?

Comment: my question is pretty important for your task, i may be able to give you more information after you answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to check if someone follows your profile. For getting to know if a user likes your page, you would need to authorize that user with the `user_likes` permission.

To check if the user likes your page without going through the whole list, you can use the following API endpoint: `/me/likes/[page-id]` ... if it returns something, the user liked the Page.